# CSS breadcrumbs Help formatting fonts

Tags: html, css, web, hyperlink, breadcrumbs

I am having some difficulty changing font color decoration ect across the same DIV tag.

What I want to do is make a breadcrumb type navigation on certain pages in my site and I would like to minimize the amount or Div's I use so as to make it easier to maintain.

here is what I have and would like to do.

```
 <div id="product-breadcrumbs">
 <div id="breadcrumbs">(Link and color) //   (another link and another color) 
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 #product-breadcrumbs {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 66px;
width: 1024px;
height: 34px;
background-color: #E7E5F2;
 }

 #breadcrumbs {
position: relative;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
text-align: left;
text-indent: 140px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #09C;
text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what "some difficulty" is.

Comment: Please elaborate on how a few extra divs will make it harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Reread your question (you are right, I did misread it). You could accomplish this by giving classes to your links, no?

```
 <div id="product-breadcrumbs">
      <div id="breadcrumbs">
           <a href="#" class="colorOne">A link</a>
           <a href="#" class="colorTwo">Another link</a> 
      </div>
 </div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
 #breadcrumbs a.colorOne {
      color: black;
 }
 #breadcrumbs a.colorTwo {
      color: blue;
 }
```

Comment: The way I read it, Ian, is that he wants the links to be different colors within the same div.

Comment: ok i didn't know you could have 2 separate link classes inside the same div.  is it possible to assign classes to something else in the div that i could use to control the color of my links independently? or will your recommendation work for that?

Comment: Yep, you can assign classes to pretty much anything. So say you have a divider between each link and you want each divider to be a different color – you can again just give them different class names.

Comment: wow ok thats awesome..  i did not know that.  I appreciate all your help guys!   and to answer the question on how a few extra div's would make maintenance harder. I have to hand the site over to a 0 experience tech to maintain and write out instructions for maintenance.